# preserve newlines in sed replacement pattern

Tags: bash, shell, sed

so I have a bash function that implements simple liquid-style templating:

```
template () {
    key=$(echo "$2" | tr -d '[:space:]')

    # escape slashes
    value=$(echo $3 | sed -e 's/\\/\\\\/g' -e 's/\//\\\//g' -e 's/&/\\\&/g') 
    echo "$1" | sed "s/{{$key}}/$value/g; s/{{$key:[^}]*}}/$value/g"
}
```

so that `template foo bar zorp` will replace `{{bar}}` with `zorp` in the given `foo` template.

my problem is that feeding the output of this function back in as a value causes the newlines to be stripped, and eventually sed errors from line-length limitations. Is there a way to escape newlines so they go through the template intact?

Comment: `tr -d '[:space:]'` deletes newlines...

Comment: right, but I'm not too concerned about the key. That's just what I'm replacing.

Comment: what about a `echo "$1" > /tmp/file; sed '...' /tmp/file` as last line ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not sed that strips your newlines, it's the way you are handling the output. If you capture the output into a new template, take care that you do not 'flatten' it.

```
foo2=$(template "$foo" bar zorp)
foo3=$(template "$foo2" moo burp)
```

Comment: so the foo3 case is actually fine when I run the template function. My main problem is foo4=$(template "$foo3" blah "$foo2"). When I pass the output back in as the replacement value, is when it gets flattened.

Comment: I see. So you mean that your replacement string may contain newlines. This wasn't clear from the original post. Look at `value=$(echo $3 | ...`, that's where the newlines get stripped. Shield them with `"$3"`